# Risk of making production org the apo?

Tags: isv, lma

What are the risks and best practices around using our production org vs the provisioed SIV org as the APO (LMA)?

Comment: Hey, this was closed by the community for being 'unclear'. The ISV provisioned org is only really a courtesy to ISV partners, if you've already got a production org you use for everything else (not your dev org) then it's perfectly normal to use that.